# Navbar items not spacing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want the links to spread out along my navbar with bootstrap. I tried using flex utilities on the navbar and I also attempted to apply the nav class to make the navbar flex-enabled and then use the .justified-content-around bootstrap class, but for some reason that I cannot see it is not wanting to work! It appears as if there are margins or padding pushing the links together on the navbar but when inspecting it with developer tools I don't see anything of the sort.
Here is my codepen to examine: https://codepen.io/Spector1/pen/WNGxzpz
Otherwise here is my html and css below.

```html
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
          <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>
          <span>Q&sdot;C&sdot;R</span>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-trigger="#MainNav" aria-controls="MainNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-around" id="MainNav">
          <div class="offcanvas-header mt-3">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
              <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>
              <span>Q&sdot;C&sdot;R</span>
            </a>
            <button class="btn btn-dark btn-close float-right" aria-label="Close navigation">
              <span>&times; Close</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item mx-auto">
              <a class="nav-link focus" href="/home">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mx-auto">
              <a class="nav-link focus" href="/about">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mx-auto dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link focus shadow-none dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Repair Pricing
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu fade-down" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Smartphones</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Smart Watches</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tablets &amp; iPads</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drones</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Laptops</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Desktops</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Other/Custom Quote</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mx-auto dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link focus shadow-none dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Warranties &amp; Policies
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu fade-down" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Repair Warranties</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rewards Program</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Repair Policies</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mx-auto">
              <a class="nav-link focus" href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <main>
        <div>
          <h1>Home/Index Page</h1>
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer>Quality Cell Repair &copy; 2020</footer>
    </body>
```

```css
    /* Mobile Nav Overlay/OffCanvas Menu Styles */
    body.offcanvas-active {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .offcanvas-header {
      display: none;
    }
    nav #MainNav button.btn-dark {
      background-color: #1d1d2c;
      border: none;
    }
    /* Nav Hamburger Menu Icon (create lines) */
    .navbar-toggler {
      margin: 1em;
      width: 65px;
      border: 2px solid #f7f4e9;
      transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }
    .navbar-toggler:hover,
    .navbar-toggler:focus {
      border: none;
      /* Remove kyboard navigation outline when focused */
      outline: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggler:after,
    .navbar-toggler:before,
    .navbar-toggler span.icon-bar {
      background-color: #f7f4e9;
      border-radius: 2px;
      content: "";
      display: block;
      height: 4px;
      margin: 5px 0;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }
    /* Create Hover Animation Effect for Mobile Nav Icon */
    .navbar-toggler:hover:before,
    .navbar-toggler:focus:before {
      transform: scale(1.2) translateY(-7px);
      height: 5px;
    }
    .navbar-toggler:hover span.icon-bar,
    .navbar-toggler:focus span.icon-bar {
      transform: scale(1.2);
      height: 5px;
    }
    .navbar-toggler:hover:after,
    .navbar-toggler:focus:after {
      transform: scale(1.2) translateY(7px);
      height: 5px;
    }
    /* Customize navbar theme */
    .navbar {
      background-color: #e83953;
    }
    /* change the Brand Icon and Icon text weight */
    .navbar .navbar-brand {
      font-weight: 500;
      color: #1d1d2c;
      font-size: 45px;
    }
    /* Change main nav link colors */
    .navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
      color: #1d1d2c;
      transition: 650ms;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-toggle {
      color: #1d1d2c;
      transition: 650ms;
    }
    /* Change main nav links color when hovering */
    .navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-toggle:hover {
      color: #f7f4e9;
    }
    .navbar .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
      color: #f7f4e9;
    }
    /* Show link selection for keyboard navigation */
    .navbar ul a.focus:focus {
      outline: none;
      color: #f7f4e9;
    }
    /* for dropdown only - change the color of dropdown */
    .navbar .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #f7f4e9;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    .navbar .dropdown-item {
      color: #e83953;
      transition: 650ms;
    }
    .navbar .dropdown-item:hover,
    .navbar .dropdown-item:focus {
      background-color: #e83953;
      color: #f7f4e9;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    /* ============= DESKTOP VIEW ============= */
    /* Navbar Dropdown animation */
    @media all and (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar .nav-item .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: 350ms;
        margin-top: 0;
      }
      .navbar .dropdown-menu.fade-down {
        top: 80%;
        transform: rotateX(-75deg);
        transform-origin: 0% 0%;
      }
      .navbar .dropdown-menu.fade-up {
        top: 180%;
      }
      .navbar .nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu,
      .navbar .nav-item:focus .dropdown-menu {
        transition: 300ms;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        top: 100%;
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
      }
    }
    /* ============ desktop view .end// ============ */
    /* ========== Mobile view ========== */
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .offcanvas-header {
        display: block;
      }
      .navbar-collapse {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
        overflow-y: auto;
        visibility: hidden;
        background-color: #e83953;
        transition: visibility 0.2s ease-in-out, transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
      }
      .navbar-collapse.show {
        visibility: visible;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
      /* Shorten link widths, except dropdowns */
      .navbar ul li > a {
        width: 15%;
      }
    }
    /* ========== Mobile view ./end ========== */
    /* ======================================================================================================== */
```

Comment: Just add `width: 100%` to the `<ul>`.

Comment: Wow....Can't believe it was that simple! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Or you can use BS4's `w-100` class for 100% width. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/sizing/